# "Could not convert string to float: b'-'"

Tags: python, arduino

**Hi I'm running this code to pick up data from a serial port and convert them into values. The data are in this form:**
b'-1.379531\n-0.050295\n'
The lines that I use to convert them into float

```
def separa_dati(text):
    try:
        return float(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text


if z1serial.is_open:
    k = 0
    while k <100:
        size = z1serial.inWaiting()
        if size:
            data = z1serial.read(size)
            print(data)
            for line in data.strip().split(b'\n'):
                x.append((list(map(separa_dati, line.split(b',')))))
            k += 1
            print(k)
        else:
            print ('no data')
        time.sleep(0.5)
else:
    print ('z1serial not open')
```

Some times the error that pup up is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'-'
```

Any hint?

Comment: The data in the form you have provided seems to work without issue. So the culprit is likely to be the `z1serial.read()` not getting complete data. Have you tried `z1serial.readline()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any operation on your data in this case, you should convert it to string, since `b'anything'` means it's in **byte** format

you can convert it into string using `data.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it doesn't solve my problem, even thought I have them in string- type, I can't convert them into float...